# How do you run a Python script in a newer Python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, interpreter

I am using several applications that are using different versions of Python:

Nuke - 2.7

3Dequalizer - 2.6

linux - 2.6.6

I am getting various problems trying to get them all to communicate with one another, so I was wondering if it's possible to change Python interpreter during a script.

E.g. Start in 2.6, then run a Python script in 2.7 from a script in 2.6

**EDIT:**

```
nuke_install = "/path/to/nuke"

cmd = nukeLauncher + " -t"
os.system(cmd)
```

The -t flag allows for nuke to be run without a GUI. This code works when run in a Python interpreter, but when I run via a Python script in 3dequalizer it gives me the:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

To add another level of confusion, I can import site inside 3dequalizer. The sys.path for 3dequalizer contains the same paths as when run directly from the interpreter, with a few additions for the python lib that comes with 3de.

Also PYTHONPATH is empty inside 3dequalizer. Does this matter if sys.path is pointing to the right paths?

Comment: Your should try writing codes that are compatible with all versions maybe.

Comment: Are you sure there is something Python-version-specific that is causing your comms problems, or are you assuming that the different versions are your problem?

Comment: I am presuming here. I've been doing lots of tests and I can't seem to get figure out what is the problem exactly. But when I run directly from each interpreter it works fine. I mainly want to be able to use 2.7 for subprocess. But when using os.system I get ImportError's saying No module named site. From some searching around that points to the python path not being set correctly. Which made me wonder whether it was to do with the different versions clashing.

Comment: I guess it's a classic XY Problem. CPython is excellent at maintaining backwards compatibility - almost any correct 2.6 code would run correctly in 2.7 interpreter. Can you please show us MCVE where your issue arise?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is really the way to go; but if you really want to do it, you could use the `os.system` command with somthing like:

```
os.system("python2.7 myscript.py")
```

which will execute the *program* python2.7 (as long as it is in your executable path) with the name of the script as its argument (before returning to the current) statement in your initial script.

But honestly, I think you should do it in some other way. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I realise it is pretty messy. Just using it more for debugging currently. Which doesn't seem to work, so I guess back to the drawing board!